# Application.ActivateHint shows hint on incorrect position on Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, hint

I am using `Application.ActivateHint(p)`, where `p: TPoint`, to show hint on specified position. But it always shows on actual mouse coordinates on Delphi XE2.

Please look to the stack:

```
Main.ApplicationEventsShowHint('Hint String Here...',True,$18FB14)
:5049c644 TCustomApplicationEvents.DoShowHint + $20
:5049d043 TMultiCaster.DoShowHint + $4B
:50454a6b TApplication.ActivateHint + $213
RxDBCtrl.TRxDBGrid.MouseMove([],934,45)
```

On `RxDBCtrl.TRxDBGrid.MouseMove` I call `TApplication.ActivateHint` with correct screen coordinates as the parameter. But on `Main.ApplicationEventsShowHint(var HintStr: string; var CanShow: Boolean; var HintInfo: THintInfo)` the value of `HintInfo.HintPos` is the same as actual mouse coordinates. The value passed as the parameter to `TApplication.ActivateHint` is lost.

Why this happens? How to show a hint on desired coordinates on Delphi XE2?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Any chance of an SSCCE?

Comment: Uhm, because `TApplication.ActivateHint` behaves [`that way`](http://imgur.com/mjCIdYc) (later on is that `HintInfo` variable passed to the `OnShowHint` event method without `HintPos` changing) ?

Comment: But there is a parameter on ActivateHint with coordinates where to show a hint. Documentation agrees with that. Also this code works on Delphi 7. Don't work on Delphi XE2.

Comment: ...And how to show a hint on desired coordinates?

Comment: David, it works correctly on simple project with StringGrid instead RxGrid...:(

Comment: @David Thanks for the pointer I bookmarked http://sscce.org/

Comment: TLama, CursorPos on the screenshot is the procedure parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems were from the following method:

```
procedure TJvDBGrid.CMHintShow(var Msg: TCMHintShow); message CM_HINTSHOW;
```

And the new property of the component:

```
type
  TJvDBGridCellHintPosition = (gchpDefault, gchpMouse);

property CellHintPosition: TJvDBGridCellHintPosition; default gchpDefault;
```

To fix the issue I use the following code before call a hint:

```
ShowCellHint := True;
CellHintPosition := gchpDefault;
```

The second line is optional. But I saw very strange `gchpMouse` value of the `CellHintPosition` property on the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a way to achieve this using the default Hint control but you might want to check out [TBalloonHint](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Controls.TBalloonHint) component which allows you to display the hint at a given position.

Here's a very easy example on how to achieve that :

```
var B : TBalloonHint;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  B := TBalloonHint.Create(Self);
  B.Style := bhsStandard;
  CustomHint := B;
end;
```

When the form is created we assign the BalloonHint component to the Main Form, any component that has the [parentCustomHint](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.ParentCustomHint) property set to True will inherit the CustomHint.

After that you can simply call the hint at the given Screen Position like this:

```
B.ShowHint(Point(X,Y)); {Where X & Y are Screen Coordinates}
```

---

For simple demonstration :

1. Create a new blank VCL project
2. Integrate the following:

   ```
   type
     TForm1 = class(TForm)
       procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
       procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
         Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
     private
       { Private declarations }
     public
       { Public declarations }
     end;



   var
     Form1: TForm1;

   implementation

   {$R *.dfm}
   var B : TBalloonHint;

   procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     Hint := 'Test';
     ShowHint := True;
     B := TBalloonHint.Create(Self);
     B.Style := bhsStandard;
     CustomHint := B;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
     Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
   var P : TPoint;
   begin
     P := Point(X,Y);
     P := ClientToScreen(P);
     B.ShowHint(P);
   end;
   ```

Comment: Thanks! But will it have the same appearance as system hint? May I use a custom font on it?

Comment: @Altaveron, TBalloonHint depends heavily on Windows Themes. To make it appear exactly like the regular hint you would have to modify the painting procedures or somehow disable theming for the TCustomHintWindow that is being used for the Hint.

Comment: @Altaveron, I don't know where you went wrong when you implemented that, I've added simple example for you to test it out.